# What's an appropriate greeting for Motzei Yom Kippur?

Tags: yom-kippur, social-convention

What's an appropriate way to greet people after Yom Kippur?

It seems to be a little late for *g'mar chatima tovah*, and many people associate *shvua tov* with Motzei Shabbat.

Comment: "Need help with your Sukkah?" :-)

Comment: In the mood for some Chinese take out? Sorry, I couldn't resist.

Comment: This seems primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While I'm accustomed to "gut voch" or "gut (gebentched) yar," I noticed that the "מחזור המפורש" (Gefen, Jerusalem 5772 [Ashkenaz, page 999]) indicates that a regular yom tov greeting (either "gut yom tov" or "chag sameach," I guess) should be used. וז"ל:

> ופוקדין איש את רעהו לשלום כדרך שאומרים בכניסת יו"ט.‏

One person actually did wish me a "good yom tov" tonight, for what it's worth.

[Yishai](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/440/yishai) pointed out some sources for this: according to Shulchan Aruch HaRav ([OC 623:12](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh4/3/623/12)), the Yom Tov greeting should be used, because Motzaei Yom Kippur is a (not so well-known) Yom Tov:

> ועוד יש טעם בתקיעה זו להראות שהוא יום טוב ולהרבות בסעודה מפני שאין
>   יום טוב זה מפורסם עשו בו תקנה לפרסמו לכן יפקדו איש את רעהו בצאתו
>   מבית הכנסת כדרך שאומרים בשבת ויום טוב

This has also been codified in [אוצר מנהגי חב"ד](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30510&st=&pgnum=263&hilite=).

[Zeev](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1507/zeev) pointed me toward the Matteh Efraim ([624:5](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9158&st=&pgnum=237)) and Pri Megadim ([623:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41250&st=&pgnum=316&hilite=)) who also record this custom.

Answer (score 13):

In addition to "good *yom tov*" and "good year" (or the Yiddish or Hebrew equivalents) mentioned in other answers, I've heard "*a gutn kvitl*" or the equivalent "*piska tava*", meaning ["a good note"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoshana_Rabbah#Themes), referring to the judgement sealed on Yom Kippur and delivered on Hoshana Rabbah.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to "gut yor", I believe I've heard "gmar tov" till Hoshana Rabba.